# Problems concatenating adjusted volume videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have taken a number of video clips and adjusted their volumes using ffmpeg before then trying to concatenate them (using ffmpeg), but whereas I can watch the individually adjusted volume clip files AND hear the adjusted volume okay, the final concatenated version contains the video but no audio.

The commands I use to adjust the volume are:

```
> ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.ts"


> ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.ts" -vol 409 -vcodec copy  "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet_v1.6.ts"
```

The command I am using the concat is:

```
> ffmpeg -y -progress progressinfo.dat -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:/_Videos/Test/concat.txt" -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/_MERGED.mp4"
```

The output from this is below, but there are multiple errors listed similar to this...

```
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. 
Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, 
it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The full output....

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libx

ml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, concat, from 'E:/_Videos/Test/concat.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 136 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'E:/_Videos/Test/_MERGED.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
.
.
.
```

I have tried several different methods to adjust the volume and I have tried this on version 4.2.3 and the latest 4.4.1 but both fail with the same error. (I am on Windows 10)

(concatenating the original .ts files without adjusting the volume works ok).

What am I doing wrong (how do you adjust the volume of an mp4 before concatenating it back in with other mp4s)?

Comment: You are not allowed to ask the same question in two Stack Exchange community sites. You have already asked in [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1697054/problems-concatenating-adjusted-volume-videos). Please delete your question from Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 0):

You are not encoding the audio into your output file, try `-acodec copy` (or  `-c:a copy`) after `-vcodec copy`